# iptables redirect hardcoded DNS requests

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm slowly trying to learn iptables and would like to redirect all DNS (port 53) requests not coming from/to a list of IPs (from 192.168.2.1, 192.168.2.29 or to 1.1.1.1). I figured I can use chains. It does not work though. Could you please give me a hint:

```
iptables -N dnsrewrite
iptables -A dnsrewrite -s 192.168.2.1 -j RETURN
iptables -A dnsrewrite -s 192.168.2.29 -j RETURN
iptables -A dnsrewrite -d 1.1.1.1 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A dnsrewrite -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.29
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 53 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 53 -j dnsrewrite
iptables -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j dnsrewrite
```

Comment: It said: `Run \`dmesg' for more information.`

Comment: There was no more info there really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
iptables -t nat -N dnsrewrite
iptables -t nat -A dnsrewrite -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.29

iptables -t nat -N whitelist
iptables -t nat -A whitelist -s 192.168.2.1 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A whitelist -s 192.168.2.29 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A whitelist -d 1.1.1.1 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A whitelist -j dnsrewrite

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 53 -j whitelist
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j whitelist
```

Whether these suit you needs depends.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 53 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j MASQUERADE
```